# inside brick chimney

Tags: chimney

I have a house, weatherboard, which has a chimney that, i think, used to service two adjacent rooms.The fireplaces have been closed in and the interior wall removed leaving a triangular shaped wall around the chimney. An old wood heater has been fitted into the triangular shape on one side.I'm told this is very unsafe.Has anyone heard of this before and any suggestions re making it safe for a wood burner? 
Thanks in anticipation
Karyn.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, some questions are not for the innerwebs.  This is one of them.

Find your local LICENSED chimney sweeper. He needs to check your chimney, make sure that not only is the chimney ready for fire, but that all additional openings that may be hidden are properly sealed off.